# What is Form load event handler in Java?

Tags: java

What is the event handler in Java (using net beans) that resembles the From_Load in C#?

Comment: Which GUI framework are you using? Swing? SWT?

Comment: Are you talking about Form_Load ? If so, please fix your typo error and maybe provide a link to relevant documentation.

Comment: I don't mind SWT or Swing. I think they are both included! At least this is what I find at the toolbox (palette)

Comment: I'm not a Java expert, but I doubt it is a good idea to mix Swing and SWT in the same application...

Comment: I am not an expert either. But now I am using only Swing. Where can I get it from?

Comment: Are you running with J2SE? If so, you should have it already.

You might want to have a look at this site here : http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using Swing's JFrame, try using addWindowListener (inherited from  java.awt.Window)

The listener's windowOpened method looks like where you want to be...

Answer (score 5):

This simple sample is useful.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame fa = new JFrame();
    fa.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 200);
    fa.setVisible(true);
    fa.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fa, "windowOpened");
        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fa, "windowClosing");
        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fa, "windowClosed");
        }

        @Override
        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fa, "windowIconified");
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fa, "windowDeiconified");
        }

        @Override
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        //                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fa, "windowActivated");
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        //                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fa, "windowDeactivated");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the accepted answer is based on the underlying `WindowListener` interface (which forces you to provide an implementation for each type of event you can use) the [WindowAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) where you can override the appropriate event you are interested in.

```
public class MySwingJFrame extends JFrame {
    public MySwingJFrame() {
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                // do something
            }
        });
    }
}
```